# Delete all records from a schema in oracle pl sql

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I am using oracle 10g.
I want to delete all the records from every table of a schema (user) with child records present.
I have tried to disable all the constraints present in every table and then try to delete the records.
But it took the whole day to do so. 
Do we have a better way to do it?

I have tried this

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables)
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from' || '"'||i.table_name||'"';
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

but exceptions comes as child records are present.
I want something like this.

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_cons_columns)
   LOOP
   for j in (select column_name from i.table_name)
   loop
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table "'||i.table_name||'"'||' disable constraint "'||j.column_name||'"';
      end loop;
 END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Please help me out a little here.

Comment: Does disabling the foreign keys take the whole day?

Comment: yes its because i have about 200 tables and 4 different schemas.

Comment: Is it possible to drop schema and recreate it in future?

Comment: yes. i will recreate it in future

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli Disabling constraints takes too much time even if you have execute your loop in 4 schemas?

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli ok, you can use data pump for your task. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data pump, export your schema:

```
expdp system/s 
directory=backup_dir 
CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY 
dumpfile=YOUR_SCHEMA_HEREmetaddl.dmp 
schemas=YOUR_SCHEMA_HERE 
logfile=YOUR_SCHEMA_HERE.$Date.log
```

then drop your schema:

```
drop user YOUR_SCHEMA_HERE cascade;
```

and then import it:

```
impdp system/s 
directory=backup_dir 
dumpfile=YOUR_SCHEMA_HEREmetaddl.dmp 
logfile=imp_log_of_meta.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following and then delete all tables which are having child records.
You could change the query to enable constraints upon deletion of all records.

```
BEGIN
   FOR c IN (    SELECT c.owner, c.table_name, c.constraint_name
    FROM user_constraints c, user_tables t
   WHERE     c.table_name = t.table_name
         AND c.status = 'ENABLED'
         AND constraint_type = 'R'
ORDER BY c.constraint_type DESC)
   LOOP
      DBMS_UTILITY.exec_ddl_statement (
            'alter table "'
         || c.owner
         || '"."'
         || c.table_name
         || '" disable constraint '
         || c.constraint_name);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```